# How to install R package from private repo using devtools install_github?

Tags: r, github, devtools

I am trying to install a sample package from my github repo:
`https://github.com/jpmarindiaz/samplepkg`

I can install it when the repo is public using any of the following commands through the R interpreter:

- `install_github("jpmarindiaz/rdali")`
- `install_github("rdali",user="jpmarindiaz")`
- `install_github("jpmarindiaz/rdali",auth_user="jpmarindiaz")`

But when the git repository is private I get an Error:

```
Installing github repo samplepkg/master from jpmarindiaz
Downloading samplepkg.zip from     
https://github.com/jpmarindiaz/samplepkg/archive/master.zip
Error: client error: (406) Not Acceptable
```

I haven't figured out how the authentication works when the repo is private, any hints?

Comment: Just a guess, Did you try to set the password argument?

Comment: sounds like a good hint!

Comment: @agstudy What I really hate about this, is that I have to enter the password in clear text (and eventually it'll be saved in `.Rhistory`). Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: @agstudy haha how could I missed it... it'd be great not to type the password in clear text!

Comment: @Beasterfield & jpmarindiaz I don't have a private repository to test , But I would clone my repository , using `git clone` or better using manually `Rstudio` (create a new package from an existing git repository) , then you install using `install()` from `devtools.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Have you tried setting a personal access token (PAT) and passing it along as the value of the `auth_token` argument of `install_github()`?

See `?install_github` way down at the bottom (Package `devtools` version 1.5.0.99).

Comment: Make sure to tick the `repo scope` button or devtools will not be able to install! http://stat545.com/packages05_foofactors-package-02.html

Comment: Since this link is broken above: You can look at step 7 in selecting the scope when making a PAT https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Answer (score 23):

Create an access token in:
https://github.com/settings/tokens

Save it (Add it) to *.Renviron* file on the `getwd()` folder, [this way](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf):
`GITHUBTOKEN=tokenstring`
Add `.Renviron` to *.gitignore* file if your folder is a repository

Or add your tokenstring system-wide to this file if pertinent:
`file.path(R.home(),"etc", "Renviron.site")`

Restart R session, to get *.Renviron* and/or *Renviron.site* files loaded automatically

Check the branch name and pass it to `ref`

```
devtools::install_github("user/repo",
                         ref = "main",
                         auth_token = Sys.getenv("GITHUBTOKEN")                          
                        )
```

Answer (score 11):

A more modern solution to this problem is to set your credentials in R using the usethis and credentials packages.

```
#set config
usethis::use_git_config(user.name = "YourName", user.email = "your@mail.com")

#Go to github page to generate token
usethis::create_github_token() 

#paste your PAT into pop-up that follows...
credentials::set_github_pat()

#now remotes::install_github() will work
remotes::install_github("username/privaterepo")
```

More help at https://happygitwithr.com/common-remote-setups.html#common-remote-setups