# "406 Not Acceptable" error when trying to use Composer to install private repo

Tags: php, git, github, composer-php, http-status-code-406

I'm trying to get my head around the PHP dependency manager [Composer](http://getcomposer.org), so that I can install a package from a private GitHub repository.

I've followed the instructions about [using private repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories) for a [test repo](https://github.com/growdigital/access-test), and I'm getting a weird [406 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) which is:

> The requested resource is only capable of generating content not
>   acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

The error message is:

```
$ composer install -n
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing growdigital/access (0.0.3)
    Downloading: connection...Failed to download growdigital/access from dist: The "https://github.com/growdigital/access/archive/0.0.3.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable)
Now trying to download from source
  - Installing growdigital/access (0.0.3)
Cloning 464c3a3a580ded3fdaf43a246388b6de33fbac89
```

So it is working insofar as installing from source rather than the zip. My question really is, how on earth do I address the 406 error? Is there something I need to do to modify composer?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in composer; 406 should mean the client has sent `Accept-*` headers such that the server has unacceptable content.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171142/how-to-install-r-package-from-private-repo-using-devtools-install-github (github may be sending spurious 406 when there's actually an auth problem?)

Comment: definitely not a bug in composer because I'm looking for answers for the same problem using pip in python