# install_github from private repository

Tags: r, github, devtools

I am trying to install R package from my companies private Github repository using devtools. I am using the below example however keep getting error JSON: EXPECTED value GOT EOF.

I tried setting options(download.file.method= "libcurl") but still getting the same error.

`install_github('{username}/{privateRpackage}', host='{companyGitHubEnterpriseURL}/api/v3/')`

Comment: `git clone` and `R CMD Build directory` and `install.packages("path to tarball")`. Otherwise, do as the docs suggest: **@param auth_token To install from a private repo, generate a personal
#'   access token (PAT) in "https://github.com/settings/tokens" and**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install R package from private repo using devtools install\_github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171142/how-to-install-r-package-from-private-repo-using-devtools-install-github)